# How to solve a first order inhomogenous recurrence relation?

Tags: recurrence-relations

I have a recurrence relation for a fund that starts a 50 million, 6 % interest every year, and an outtake of 2 million/year. How to find out a solution for what funds exists after n years?

$$x_{n+1}=x_{n}*1.06-2$$     $$ x_{0}=50$$

Under are my calculations -

Assosiated homogenous relation : $$x_{n+1}=1.06x_{n}$$

Special solution : $$x_{n+1}=1.06x_{n}-2  = x_{n}^{s}=33.3334$$

General solution : $$x_{n}=C*(1.06)^n+33.3334$$

How to calculate the last unknown C? The answer in the book says its 50/3, but i really can't get my head around why its not just 50 as the $x_{0}$ is.

(Sorry in advance if i have misspelled some of the solution names or the equation part names, i've tried translating them from norwegian. Help on correct translations is appreciated.)

Comment: First write 33.3334= 100/3.  Then   x0 = C + 100/3 it is to say 50 = C + 100/3.  Then C = 50/3.  Do you agree?

Comment: Your line with the "Special solution" is not clear. You'd better write "a constant value $x_{n+1}=x_n=K$, such that $K=1.06K-2$, works".